# when using cmd findstr, how do i output "No matches found" when no matches are actually found in text file?

Tags: cmd

I am searching strings through multiple text files (in same folder). I would like to see some output even when no match found. How can I write this?

This only prints file/lines when a match is found:

```
findstr /i "blah" C:\Users\myfolder\*
```

If no match found, then I want the output to print "No match found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` works as "if previous command failed then":

```
findstr /i "blah" c:\users\myfolder\* || echo No match found
```

There is alsow a "if previous command was successful then": `&&`

Those constructs are described on [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

```
for %%a in (c:\users\myfolder\*) do findstr /i "blah" "%%a" && echo Match found || No match
```

Comment: thank you! Is there any way to specify each file before saying "no match found"? How do I call and print each file?

Comment: not with `findstr` alone. Use a `for` loop (see my edited answer)